# filter rows based on text in column

Tags: unix, filter, awk

I have a tab delimited text file as shown below:

```
27  1   hom het:het    het,het,het,het
18  1   hom het:het    hom,het,het,het,het,het,het
29  1   hom het:het    hom,hom,hom,hom,hom,hom,hom,hom,hom,hom,hom,hom,hom,hom
13  1   hom het:het    het,het,het,het,het,het
21  1   hom het:het    hom,het,het,het,het,het,hom,het,hom,het,het,het,hom
25  1   hom het:het    het,hom,het,het,het
29  1   hom het:het    hom,hom,het,hom,het,het,hom,het,het,hom,het,hom,het,hom
18  1   hom het:het    het,het,het
19  1   hom het:het    het,het,hom,het,het,het,het,het,het,hom,het,het,hom,het
```

I want to exclude the rows which have 'hom' in the 5th column. i.e. the output should look like:

```
27  1   hom het:het    het,het,het,het
13  1   hom het:het    het,het,het,het,het,het
18  1   hom het:het    het,het,het
```

Any help using unix command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Awk is perfect for this:

```
$ awk '$5!~/\<hom\>/' file
27  1   hom het:het    het,het,het,het
13  1   hom het:het    het,het,het,het,het,het
18  1   hom het:het    het,het,het
```

Explanation:

```
$5         # is the fifth column
!~         # negated regex match 
/          # start regex string
\<         # matches the empty string at the beginning of a word.
hom        # matches the literal string 'hom'
\>         # matches the empty string at the end of a word.
/          # end regex string
```

Comment: Maybe use `awk -F '\t'` in case there are columns with non-separator whitespace in the real data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt using `sed`

```
sed -r '/(\S+\s+){4}[^\s]*\b(hom)\b/d' file
```

Output:

```
27  1   hom het:het    het,het,het,het
13  1   hom het:het    het,het,het,het,het,het
18  1   hom het:het    het,het,het
```